# How to center align two divs having a parent div

Tags: html, css

If I am having two divs in a parent div and and all three divs have float left. What I have to do is to align center the two child divs without removing float left.

Comment: Can you provide your html/css?

Comment: all three divs means these divs are child div?

Comment: Please put your code in a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on child divs and you can give `text-align: center` to the parent div.

Comment: use vertical-align: top on the inline-block divs if they are not aligned properly

Answer (score 1):

**This layout may help you:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-p">
    <div class="div-1"></div>
    <div class="div-2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybj1fryc/5/)**

```
.div-p{background-color:#eee;width:640px;height:400px;float:left;}
.div-1{background-color:#f00;width:300px;height:300px;float:left;margin:10px;}
.div-2{background-color:#0f0;width:300px;height:300px;float:left;margin:10px;}
```

If you want to center the parent `div` then use `margin:0 auto;` and remove the `float:left;`

**CSS** - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybj1fryc/4/)**

```
.div-p{background-color:#eee;width:640px;height:400px;margin:0 auto;}
.div-1{background-color:#f00;width:300px;height:300px;float:left;margin:10px;}
.div-2{background-color:#0f0;width:300px;height:300px;float:left;margin:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i have understood,so you have something like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="float:left;">

<div id="child1" style="float:left;"></div>
<div id="child2" style="float:left;"></div>

</div>
```

And if im right you want the two div childs to be aligned in the center of the parent div but without removing the left float of none of them.Then i think this might work:

```
<div id="parent" style="float:left;position:absolute;">

<div id="child1" style="float:left; position:relative; left: 100px"></div>
<div id="child2" style="float:left; position:relative; left: 100px"></div>

</div>
```

So in the div style,try to center it by assigning a value in percentage or pixels to left: 
It should work.I also advice you to use percentage,but first use pixels to understand how it works.And another advice is to not use css in html tags,i just showed you what to do,but it's recommended to have another file (style.css) to include in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent{width:100%;}
#child1,#child2{width:90%;margin:0px 5%;}
```

set your child width in percentage with margin.
it will align both child div in center

Answer (score 0):

you need set these styles for 2 child divs :

```
{ width:50%; text-align:center; float:left; height:50px;}
```

and the parent div :

```
{ width:100%; margin: 0 auto; float:left; height:50px;}
```

Note: height style is optional.