# How to align two divs(logo and menu) in a parent div?

Tags: html, css, menu

It looks like `display: inline-block;` does not seem to work. I'm trying to find some css that can align the logo and the menu.

Can you help? :-)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="fr">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <title>GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="parent">

            <div class="logo">

                <a href="index.php">

                    <img src="images/logo.png" title="GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)" alt="Le logo de GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)." />

                </a>

            </div>

            <div class="nomprenom">

                <?php

                    $autorisation = false;
                    if ($autorisation)
                    {
                        echo "$nom $prenom";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                ?>
                    <nav class="menu">

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Inscription</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Connexion</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </nav>

                <?php

                    }

                ?>

            </div>

            <div class="enfant-un child">

                <h1>Groupement Banque-Assurance Français</h1>
                <p>Présentation des partenaires</p>
                <img class="illustration" src="images/illustration.jpg" alt="Bureaux de GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)."/>

            </div>

            <div class="enfant-deux child">

                    <h2>Acteurs et partenaires</h2>
                    <p>Présentation des acteurs et partenaires</p>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-1.png" alt="Acteur 1"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 1</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-2.png" alt="Acteur 2"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 2</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-3.png" alt="Acteur 3"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 3</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-4.png" alt="Acteur 4"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 4</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-5.png" alt="Acteur 5"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 5</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-6.png" alt="Acteur 6"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 6</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="enfant-trois child">

                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Mentions légales</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}

.parent
{

    background-color: blue;

}

.enfant-un
{

    background-color: green;

}

.enfant-deux
{

    background-color: red;

}

.enfant-trois
{

    background-color: violet;

}

.logo
{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;

}

.menu
{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 66%;

}

.illustration
{


    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center align two divs having a parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443004/how-to-center-align-two-divs-having-a-parent-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use float to have them show on the same line.

```css
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}

.parent
{

    background-color: blue;

}

.enfant-un
{

    background-color: green;

}

.enfant-deux
{

    background-color: red;

}

.enfant-trois
{

    background-color: violet;

}

.logo
{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;

}

.nomprenom 
{
  float:right;
}
.menu
{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 66%;

}

.illustration
{


    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="fr">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <title>GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="parent">

            <div class="logo">

                <a href="index.php">

                    <img src="images/logo.png" title="GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)" alt="Le logo de GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)." />

                </a>

            </div>

            <div class="nomprenom">

                <?php

                    $autorisation = false;
                    $nom = "ZAIR";
                    $prenom = "David";
                    if ($autorisation)
                    {
                        echo "$nom $prenom";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                ?>
                    <nav class="menu">

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Inscription</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Connexion</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </nav>

                <?php

                    }

                ?>

            </div>

            <div class="enfant-un child">

                <h1>Groupement Banque-Assurance Français</h1>
                <p>Présentation des partenaires</p>
                <img class="illustration" src="images/illustration.jpg" alt="Bureaux de GBAF(Groupement Banque-Assurance Français)."/>

            </div>

            <div class="enfant-deux child">

                    <h2>Acteurs et partenaires</h2>
                    <p>Présentation des acteurs et partenaires</p>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-1.png" alt="Acteur 1"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 1</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-2.png" alt="Acteur 2"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 2</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-3.png" alt="Acteur 3"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 3</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-4.png" alt="Acteur 4"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 4</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-5.png" alt="Acteur 5"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 5</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

                <div class="acteur">

                    <img src="images/logo-acteur-6.png" alt="Acteur 6"/>
                    <h3>Acteur 6</h3>
                    <p>Description + lien</p>
                    <button href="#" class="lirelasuite">Lire la suite</button>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="enfant-trois child">

                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Mentions légales</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```